# travis-CI error after pull request

Tags: python, github, travis-ci, pull-request, tox

I've done my first pull request on github recently.
The project i try to contribute to is written in python, and it uses tox and travis CI.
When i look at github.com/author/project/pulls, i see "Error: The Travis CI build could not complete due to an error" message near my request.
Never worked with CI tools before, but apparently all builds have failed (as i understand, it tries to build for python versions 2.6, 2.7 and 3.4).
So i've looked up travis logs (travis-ci.org/author/project/builds/my_build_number). Here are configs for one of the builds:

```
{
  "language": "python",
  "python": 2.7,
  "env": "TOXENV=py34",
  "install": "pip install --quiet --use-mirrors tox",
  "script": "tox",
  "after_script": [
    "if [ $TOXENV == \"cov\" ]; then pip install --quiet --use-mirrors coveralls; coveralls; fi"
  ],
  "group": "stable",
  "dist": "precise",
  "os": "linux"
}
```

and this is what the logs look like:

```
$ export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
$ git clone --depth=50 https://github.com/author/project.git author/project
Setting environment variables from .travis.yml
$ export TOXENV=py34
$ source ~/virtualenv/python2.7/bin/activate
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip install --quiet --use-mirrors tox
no such option: --use-mirrors
The command "pip install --quiet --use-mirrors tox" failed and exited with 2 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

As i see it fails because it tries to launch pip with "--use-mirros" option (which was indeed deprecated and later completely removed from pip).
So, question is: could this be an error on my side or does it happen because author uses incorrect configs?

Comment: Yes, you should remove --use-mirrors from the config. The author probably didn't update it for a while.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
For some reason i was sure all tests are run using author`s travis.yml settings, not mine.

Comment: Posting as an answer then ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should remove `--use-mirrors` from the config file, since its not used anymore and makes the build fail.

The author probably didn't updated the repository for a while (or only the config).

Best ;-)